# Creating tkinter widgets that can dynamically change configs

Tags: python, tkinter

I have built a small tkinter program that I want to have a few different themes it can change between. In order to dynamically change the colours/font for each widget I have subclassed tkinter, and I am just wondering if there is any smarter way of doing this? I am aware that ttk can do something similar, but then as I understand it you are forced to use one of the ttk themes, rather than the standard tkinter widget design

Example for the button widget:

```py
class Button(tk.Button):
    objects = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__class__.objects.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def set_config(cls, **val):
        for obj in cls.objects:
            obj.config(val)

    def destroy(self):
        cur_obj = next(idx for idx, x in enumerate(self.objects) if x.bindtags() == self.bindtags())
        del self.__class__.objects[cur_obj]
        super().destroy()
```

Comment: It should be asked in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) of StackExchange.

Comment: configure the theme then do, ```root.update()``` ?

Comment: if you want at once to reconfigure all defined widgets, not at creation but at a later point in time, then the "configure" doesn't help much. But yes probably should ask in code review. Thanks!

Comment: @oskros ~ You seem to misunderstand greatly. For `tk` the `configure` method is exactly how you would do this, and for `ttk` you could create all the custom styles you want and change them whenever you want by simply reassigning the `style` option. Neither method is complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example that attempts to consider that you will ultimately have a lot more than just 2 options to set, and you don't want to have to keep writing the same keywords over and over. The `deque` is just a cheap way for me to get the button to cycle endlessly through the themes for this example. The real meat-and-potatoes is in the fact that we're essentially just dumping a `dict` of differing values into `configure` as `kwargs`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from collections import deque
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Label_dc:
    foreground:str = None
    background:str = None

#prepare all theme kwargs
themes = deque([asdict(Label_dc("#111", "#eee")), 
                asdict(Label_dc("#eee", "#111"))])

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="theme switching", **themes[0])
label.grid()

tk.Button(root, text='switch', command=lambda:(themes.rotate(), label.configure(**themes[0]))).grid()

root.mainloop()
```